# Papertrail versioning & storing current versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I've added the Papertrail gem to my app after approx 1000 records have already been created.

Does anyone know how to populate the versions table with the current versions of my data?

Without doing this it seems only the second change for each will allow me to properly make comparisions / flag what has changed via diffing etc.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty method would be to just create a loop that updates a single field, like adding a space to string field or something harmless.